# Behavior of stop-opacity in radialGradient in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

**Background**

In the [SVG2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#StopColorProperties) we can read that:

> The opacity value used for the gradient calculation is the product of
>   the value of stop-opacity and the opacity of the value of stop-color.
>   For stop-color value types of that don't include explicit opacity
>   information, the opacity of that component must be treated as 1.

**Question**

Why does setting `stop-opacity: 0` on a *100% gradient stop* (for example), not make that gradient stop completely transparent?

You can see the green in the code below.

Pointers to text in the spec that explains this behavior, would be appreciated.

**Code**

```html
<svg height="150" width="200">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);stop-opacity:0" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="75" rx="100" ry="75" fill="url(#grad1)" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

**EDIT 1**

I was using Chrome for these tests. The opacity does work as expected in Firefox.

**EDIT 2**

Removed `fx` `fy` to demonstrate that problem still remains, even without those.

Comment: what browsers? SVG2 seems to be good only on chrome I guess. (I don't see the same on FF btw)

Comment: Very interesting @TemaniAfif . In Firefox it displays as expected. Huh... Is SVG not widely supported yet?

Comment: SVG2 not yet as per my knowledge (not all the features)... also the Spec you are reading is a working Draft.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is a bit confusing to me. Is there no support to display SVGs with gradients? What if I had made the image in Adobe Illustrator and it had radialGradient in it. If I added the image as an external SVG, would it still not work?

Comment: read this one and see:https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#RadialGradients .. it's probably a bug at the end. Anyway, wait for Robert or Paul, they will give you more precise details

Comment: Yes, that recommended spec is almost identical. So, this is not because it isn't supported. Perhaps this is a bug in Chrome, as you say. I am now trying to create an external SVG in illustrator, to see if that renders correctly.

Comment: opacity on a radial gradient is part of SVG 1.1 I guess it's just a Chrome bug.

Comment: @RobertLongson The correct behavior is that with stop-opacity: 0, the gradient stop color should not be seen at all, correct? I tried Firefox, Chrome, IE and Edge, and only Firefox showed no color (i.e. the behavior I expected). This seems to be a pretty serious bug. I mean, not displaying one of the most popular image graphic formats correctly. Where would I report such an issue?

Comment: @RobertLongson Unfortunately, the issue persists even without those. I tried creating an SVG with radial gradient in Adobe Illustrator, and viewing it in different browsers. Same issue.

Comment: @RobertLongson `fx` and `fy` are SVG 1.1 features, it's only `fr` that was added in SVG 2.

Comment: @ccprog thanks, old age must have finally caught up with me.

Answer (score 0):

The SVG 1.1 spec doesn't say much on the subject of interpolating colors between stops. But all the renderers I have seen so far are in concordance with this SVG 2 spec statement:

> For linear and radial gradients, the color value between two stops along the gradient vector is the linear interpolation, per channel, of the color for each stop, weighted by the distance from each stop.

It's not explicitely said that opacity is treated as a channel in this context, but again that is what renderers do: If there are two gradient stops with color1 and opacity=1 and color2 and opacity=0, then the color at an intermediate point is a linear interpolation between the color values, and the opacity is partial.

For your example color will change like this:

- color stop at 0%: red 255, green 0, blue 0, opacity 1
- color interpolation at 25%: red 192, green 64, blue 0, opacity 0.75
- color interpolation at 50%: red 128, green 128, blue 0, opacity 0.5
- color interpolation at 75%: red 64, green 192, blue 0, opacity 0.25
- color stop at 100%: red 0, green 255, blue 0, opacity 0

As the color fades, it goes from red to green:

[image: Radial gradient from opaque red to tranparent green]

I can see this with almost all browsers I have access to: Chrome 70/Windows, Chromium 70/Debian, Firefox 60esr/Debian, Firefox 62/Debian, Edge, IE11. The only exeption is Firefox on Windows: v62/63 show a gradient going from opaque red to transparent red:

[image]

From my point of view, it is Firefox that is in error here.

Comment: Thank you cc. To me, it seems like that contradicts the spec paragraph I quoted above: "...opacity value used for the gradient calculation is the product of the value of stop-opacity and the opacity of the value of stop-color...". Since 0*anyThing is always 0, never 0.1, I have a hard time concluding as you did.

Comment: That is the value **at** the stop, but not the interpolated value **between** stops. The important thing to note is that transparent red (`rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)`) and transparent green (`rgba(0, 255, 0, 0`) are two different colors.

Comment: On my Mac Firefox I see the top image, not the bottom one.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1509396

Comment: Gentlemen, logically I find it odd that it should be transparent *at* the stop, but not between them. My guess is that Firefox has the right interpretation here. If you set 0 opacity, it does not seem right to move towards some other arbitrary (non-specified) opacity between two stops.

Comment: Opacity in CSS is used as the basis for [alpha blending](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#alpha): when a color is rendered over some background, the resulting color is a weighted mix of foreground and background, `opacity` giving the percentige with which the foreground is taken into account. As such, opacity can take a continuous value between 0 and 1. As Gradients, by their very nature, compute intermediate values between given stops (see the used [formula](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#Gradients)), it would be actually strange if opacity was treated otherwise.